# customize ionic searchable component

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using basic ionic searchable component and it's working fine,

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Port</ion-label>
    <select-searchable
        item-content
        [(ngModel)]="port"
        [items]="ports"
        itemValueField="id"
        itemTextField="name"
        [canSearch]="true"
        (onChange)="portChange($event)">
    </select-searchable>
</ion-item>
```

The problem is that I've a pretty big array, around 8k records, and it loads really slow, how can I overcome that? any ideas? 
Can I display a small chunk of the data but still search in the whole array?
thanks.

here's the component I'm working with.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-select-searchable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out a smarter solution like so:-

I created a [Modal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/) that pops up in a different view which loads all the list in there, where i used the default search bar in ionic [Search Bar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/) which can be customized for 2D array, and there i could use [Virtual Scroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/) because i needed to search in all array, so i couldn't use [Infinite scroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/)

which i found in this [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnTKqDT0e5A) so helpful, and that helps like a charm.
hope this helps some one. thanks.

Comment: much better way with dealing with longer lists, could pass data back from modals in the view as a selectable option with data binding. thanks

Answer (score 3):

This issue arises due to some reasons like,

1. If your database is slow then you will get this issue.
2. Due to outdated ionic version
3. Due to fetching a high amount of data at a time

For further reference follow those links below

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12558
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10087

Comment: got any ideas how to display a loader or something like that?

Comment: did you check out the component i mentioned?

Comment: Yes, I checked it about component that you are used

Comment: yeah but where would i provide a loader? got any idea? not sure i have control over that ? after i click it?

Comment: for example, you can use the loader component where you are fetching data from the database.

Comment: yeah i know that, but the data is already present there, the issue is while the selector is displaying the data, u know what i mean?

Comment: Yeah I understand you can add a loader by calling a loader function in select searchable tag

Comment: good idea, but how can i trigger the stop of the loader? you should add this part to the answer so i can mark it accepted.

Comment: use  loader.present(); to start your loader place this before trigger function and use loader.dismiss(); after the trigger function